# Unable to delete recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my recylerview item, there is an option to delete the item. I am trying to achieve it in this way from activity class :

```
list.remove(position);
recyclerView.removeViewAt(position);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method notifyItemRemoved(I)V in class RecyclerviewAdapter
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Try after disable proguard in debug mode if it works the you have to add rules for support library.

Comment: remove last 3 lines of code and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `list.remove(position);`. **list** object should be same which you have passed into the adapter object.

Comment: remove the item from recyclerview adapter data set, then call notifydatasetchanged on recyclerview adapter; this is way easier.

Comment: Solved, Initially there was a proguard issue, after using @Keep annotation in POJO class, problem is solved.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to remove it by getting a position in Recycler view. Please refer any unique id or unique attribute of that element for it. If there are no unique elements in your objects in recycling view, please add the unique id.

Then get unique id when the user clicks an item in recycle view. After that search through whole the list and delete a relevant item from a list using a unique id